# NSArray: Detect And Remove Non-Existent Objects (Files)

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, itunes, aqgridview

Using [AQGridview](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) and the apple provided [DocInteraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html) sample, I can represent the files in my app bundle and files provided through iTunes in the documents directory of my app in a grid format (duh).  If I connect my iPad and add a file through iTunes, it adds it just fine, but when I delete a file from iTunes with the app still open, it doesn't delete the file from the grid or the array.  It doesn't even raise an error when I tap on the file, it just opens an empty or blank file.  How can I remove items from the array they are stored in with a foreach or forin loop (because I know that's ultimately the answer) if said item also doesn't exist in iTunes (or rather the documents directory)?

EDIT: in the context of AQGridView, my code is detecting a change in the documents directory, and is updating the NSMutableArray of objects, but the change is not being reflected on the grid.  the             `[self.gridView deleteItemsAtIndices:<#(NSIndexSet *)#> withAnimation:<#(AQGridViewItemAnimation)#>];` method seems to not work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume your NSArray is filled with paths as NSStrings.

```
NSArray *existingPaths = [paths filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *path, NSDictionary *bindings){
    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
}]];
```

Comment: 2011-11-23 16:46:47.135 SheetMuse[4570:707] -[__NSGlobalBlock__ evaluateWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x46578
2011-11-23 16:46:47.140 SheetMuse[4570:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSGlobalBlock__ evaluateWithObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x46578'

Comment: I forgot the NSPredicate constructor.  I have changed my answer.

Comment: OK, I'm testing it right now.  So far so good.

EDIT: No Dice!   Sorry, but I think it has more to do with the - (void)directoryDidChange:(DirectoryWatcher *)folderWatcher method not being called.  Thanks for your answer, I'm sure it will help someone else.